# $R$ is an associative ring with no zero divisors that has an element $a\neq 0$, such that $a*a=a$. Prove $a$ is the identity element of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R(+,*)$ be an associative ring with no zero divisors that has an element $a\neq 0$, such that $a*a=a$. Prove that $a$ is the multiplicative identity element of $R$.

I found similar questions posted here, but none of them had $a*a=a$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $a*(ax-x)=0                     $